# FATAL Cannot find module 'vue-router/package.json'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vuejs2

I am using Vue2 and vue-router/package.json.

package.json

```
 {
"resolutions": {
    "vue-router": "3.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.10.3"
  }
}
```

does someone has same problems. could you help my problem?

node- >= 14

vue2

could not build[image]